# NAudio - pause, then resume

Tags: c#, naudio

Why sometimes after `waveOut.Pause` when I do `waveOut.Resume` audio starts stuttering very bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `Play` instead of `Resume`.

Comment: Resume has a bug. It is not part of the IWavePlayer interface in any case - Play Pause and Stop are all you need.